# Making bash file to display to terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, tail, python-venv

I'm having issues with getting

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
python3 run.py > console.log.txt 2>&1 & tail -f console.log.txt
deactivate
```

to display anything on the terminal when I put it in a .sh and try to bash run it. It works when I run that command in the terminal directly. Is there anyway I can fix this?

running bash -x startup.sh displays:

```
+ source ./venv/bin/activate
++ '[' ./venv/bin/activate = start.sh ']'
++ deactivate nondestructive
++ unset -f pydoc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -n /usr/bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
++ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
++ VIRTUAL_ENV=/mnt/c/Users/billc/Documents/Websites/donttouchyourface/backend/venv
++ export VIRTUAL_ENV
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Python38/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Python38/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/bin:/mnt/c/tomcat:/mnt/c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-11.0.7_10:/mnt/c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-11.0.7_10/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin/:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/tools/mysql/current/bin:/mnt/c/tools/neovim/Neovim/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.4/bin:/snap/bin'
++ PATH='/mnt/c/Users/billc/Documents/Websites/donttouchyourface/backend/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Python38/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Python38/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/bin:/mnt/c/tomcat:/mnt/c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-11.0.7_10:/mnt/c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-11.0.7_10/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin/:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/tools/mysql/current/bin:/mnt/c/tools/neovim/Neovim/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/billc/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.4/bin:/snap/bin'
++ export PATH
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=
++ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+++ basename /mnt/c/Users/billc/Documents/Websites/donttouchyourface/backend/venv
++ PS1='(venv) '
++ export PS1
++ alias pydoc
++ true
++ '[' -n /usr/bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
+ tail -f console.log.txt
+ python3 run.py
```

Comment: That should work the same in a script. What goes wrong?

Comment: Hey Barmar, trying to run it from a script does not display anything in the terminal.

It's due to the line "source ./venv/bin/activate" that is preventing it from displaying anything in the terminal, how shall I avoid this issue? Thank you

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to `venv`.

Comment: It most likely is. I do not know how to resolve it, though

Comment: Please run the script with `bash -x yourscript` and post the complete, unmodified, unabbreviated output

Comment: I've edited the question with the results of bash -x startup.sh

Comment: Looks fine. Can you please confirm that you tried `python3 run.py > console.log.txt 2>&1 & tail -f console.log.txt` in a terminal and found it working, and that you didn't instead try `python3 run.py` and assumed it would be the same? PS: It looks like you're running this on Windows and not Linux

Comment: Yup I used the same command, and I am a linux subsystem (WSL 1) on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

pwd
echo
cd ~/<your_folder_where_venv_folder_is_present>; source venvPython375/bin/activate
echo "-- Inside Virtual ENV dir: `pwd`"
python3 run.py > console.log.111.txt 2>&1 &  timeout 5 tail -f  console.log.111.txt
echo "-- Deactivating from Venv"
deactivate
echo
```

As you are not telling `tail` when to stop, it'll keep waiting for your user input and never return back. Using `timeout 5` or any number can help.

My example **run.py** was:

```
#!/bin/python

import os
for k, v in os.environ.items():
    print(f'{k}={v}')
```